# Grails: Integration Test an Ajax request - xhr

Tags: java, ajax, grails, groovy, integration-testing

How can I set up an ajax request test to a controller in Grails?

I have tried

```
    def homeController = new HomeController()

    homeController.request.contentType = "text/json"
    homeController.request.content = '{"event_id":2}'.getBytes()
    homeController.request.xhr = true //error: can't be set

    homeController.landingPage()
```

Within my "landingPage" action I have

```
Controller
...
...
 if(params.event_id){
     //set values of the "event" object
 }

 if (request.xhr) {

       def result = [eventTile: event.getAt(0).title, eventId: event.getAt(0).id]

            render result as JSON
            return
        }
...
...
```

I couldn't find a way to reach the params field without specifying it normally.

```
 homeController.params.event_id = 2
```

So how can I setup a Grails integration test to set xhr as true which will return JSON from my controller?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `homeController.metaClass.getRequest = { [xhr:true] }`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am not getting the question right. But have found that you can use this way to force your request to be considered as xhr request.

```
def homeController = new HomeController()

homeController.request.content = '{"event_id":2}'.getBytes()
homeController.request.makeAjaxRequest()
homeController.landingPage()
```

The returned value will be a [GrailsMockHttpServletResponse](http://grails.org/doc/1.4.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/testing/GrailsMockHttpServletResponse.html)

```
homeController.response.json == "" //Make your tets here
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried addParameter? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html#addParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29